# Equivalence classes for $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ where $((a,b),(c,d)) ∈ R$ if and only if $a−d = c−b$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $R$ be the relation on $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ where $((a,b),(c,d) ∈ R$ if and only if $a−d = c−b$.

(a) Define a function $f$ such that $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ if and only if $((a,b),(c,d))$ exist in $R$.

**Edit:** I discovered that $f(x,y) = x+y$ satisfies the function requirement. I no longer need help with this part!

(b) Describe the equivalence classes. How many classes are there and how many elements in each class?

I am completely lost as to how I would even start to approach these problems, especially the equivalence classes because all examples I saw had an ordered pair or a smaller set with them instead of all integers. Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Rearrange $a-d=c-b$ to be of the form $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$. (Hint: you need to get $a,b$ on the left and $c,d$ on the right.)

Comment: @arctictern I actually just figured that out, thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

(I assume that $Z$ means $\mathbb{Z} :=$ the set of integers.)

You have figured out that two pairs of integers are equivalent if they have the same sum.

So, for example, the following are equivalent: $(0,0), (1,-1), (-1,1), (2,-2),(-2,2), \ldots$

They are equivalent because they all have the same sum: $0$

Similarly, you can make a list of all elements that have sum $1$; these will all be equivalent.

Then you could do the same for sum $-1$, or sum $2$, or sum $-2$, or ... well, for any integer.

Hopefully this helps in figuring out part (b) of your question.

Comment: Yes, it does (sorry, I'm new to the website and not quite sure how to do notations). Would I be correct in saying that it would be infinite?

Comment: @Anonymous Yes, there are infinitely many classes - one for each integer - *and* each equivalence class contains infinitely many elements (just as you can imagine how the class with sum $0$ could be extended indefinitely).

Comment: @Anonymous As to notation, \mathbb{Z} in dollar signs produces $\mathbb{Z}$. Similar for $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ or (etc).